# css3 transition: different time value when :hover In than Out?

Tags: css, css-transitions

Basically i am trying to have different transition time when the item is hovered than when the item is mouse leaved,

```
#bar{ position:fixed; bottom:-25px; }  /*here you only get to see a piece of the bar    */

#bar:hover{ transform: .2s linear; bottom:0; }
```

And something like

```
/*this only represents my made out status to cover what i need*/
#bar:mouseLeaved{ transform: 2s linear }
```

This way it would take .2 seconds to be shown and 2 seconds to be hidden

Can i do this with no need of javascript?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd suggest this:

```
#bar { transition: 2s linear; }
#bar:hover { transition: .2s linear; }
```

And, let the ordering of the CSS handle things for you when :hover is in effect (it will override the other).

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Hufxa/

Comment: Note: I think you meant to be using "transition" instead of "transform" with your transition times so I edited my answer to show that.