# css3 cubic-bezier timing function in and out

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have a css3 transition, I've used a cubic-bezier timing function for it that works correctly on the way in but not on the way out.  I have a feeling what's happening is it runs the cubic-bezier forward on the animation out, and then forwards again on the way out, but instead what I'm trying to do is have it reverse the cubic-bezier curve on the way out.

You can see when you hover over the box it swings out fast and then slows, and then when you release the hover it moves out super fast.  Here it is in action, not 100 percent sure how to fix this.

http://jsbin.com/aPunAca/2/edit

Comment: nothing happens on this example : http://jsbin.com/aPunAca/2  **maybe becoz you only styled your animation for -webkit-transition** ??

Comment: yea, I"m just experimenting so I didn't add all the prefixes, works fine in chrome/safari

Comment: figured it out, then answer can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863583/css3-transition-different-time-value-when-hover-in-than-out